# Add a class to last 3 list items in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list that is generated via ng-repeat. E.g i have the html like this

```
<ul class="my-list">
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class of .last-itmes to the last 3 list items using angular. How can i do this?

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `ng-repeat`, Angular provides `$index`, `$first`, `$last` to get the index position of list item.

In your case you can use `$last` and substract from it like `$last-1`, `$last-2`.

Sample code :

```
    <li ng-repeat="item in itemList"
       ng-class="{'last':($index === $last) || ($index === ($last-1)) ||  ($index === ($last-2))}"
     >List Item
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see demo below

ie:

```
ng-class="{'last-itmes':$index>=data.length-3}"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

});
```

```css
.last-itmes {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <ul class="my-list">
      <li ng-repeat="i in data" ng-class="{'last-itmes':$index>=data.length-3}">{{i}}</li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you can go for **Directives** which is a neat and clean way

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.datas = ['List Item', 
                    'List Item', 
                    'List Item', 
                    'List Item', 
                    'List Item', 
                    'List Item', 
                    'List Item', 
                    'List Item'];
})

.directive("itemWatch", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            index: '=index',
            length: '=length'
        },
        replace: false,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, Controller) {
            if ($scope.length - $scope.index <= 3) {
                $element.addClass('last-itmes');
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

```css
.last-itmes
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <ul class="my-list">
        <li ng-repeat="item in datas track by $index" index="$index" length="datas.length" item-watch>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i like the answer but i don't want go with directives because i already have alot of directives to get the data inside the list. So i would prefer something  directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with `js object` and `ng-show`.

```
var items = [
  {id:1,isLast:false}
  {id:2,isLast:true}
  {id:3,isLast:true}
]
```

And your html with angularjs:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div class="last-items" ng-show="item.isLast">
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your ng-repeat, you can use `track by $index` to determine which position you are on. Doing that, you can easily do things within the repeat. To get it to add a class for just the last three items, you can put a condition on the `ng-class` directive like so:

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="row in people track by $index">
    <tr ng-class="{'blue': $index > people.length - 4 }">
      <td>
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">{{ row }}</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

I've made a plunker to show an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/g24eYggfIRFS2El8R5Mu